# What is unilateral continuity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis, continuity

I wanted to ask if anyone knows what unilateral continuity is. In particular, I am considering the multiplication map of  group from $G\times G$ to $G$. This is being used in one of the papers I am trying to read, but I can't seem to find a definition anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: *Unilateral* sounds like it could mean "one-sided".  Is $G$ a topological group?

Comment: It could be helpful to provide a citation for the paper you are reading.

Comment: yeah! Actually this might make sense. So you mean separate continuity?

Comment: I would guess something of that kind.  For $G$ to be a topological group, which turns out to be rather a special case, you want the multiplication map to be continuous in the sense of mapping the product topology  to $G$.  I suppose it might be more general to allow for the multiplication map to be continuous in each "factor" separately.  I've never thought about this.

Comment: This is a common concept in my area. A group like that is called semitopological.  I guess I should have corrected myself - G is not a topological group but rather a group with a topology on it! Silly me! And I am reading 

R. Ellis. Locally compact transformation groups. Duke. Math. J. Vol. 24 (1957), 119-125.

Thanks for the suggestion! It makes sense.